# How to create a view in eclipse which contains SWT components?

Tags: java, eclipse, view

I am trying to create a view in eclipse. I want my view to contain a Textfield and a button. the action is triggered by clicking on the button and some processing will be done on the inserted query in the textfield. can anyone suggest me a link to a tutorial or example doing that?
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create two quick samples that together show you what you've asked for.  You do that by using the new project wizard to create a plugin project.  One of the last wizard pages has a list of templates to choose from.  If you create a plugin using the "with a view" template, you'll see how to create a view.  Go back and create a second plugin with the "multi-page editor" template and you'll see examples of buttons, their event handlers and text fields.  It should be easy to see how to code up the buttons and texts in the view.